# How can I keep the BarcodeScanner screen open without redirecting me to another page?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am making an application that allows me to scan QR codes, and I managed to make the code work but my doubt is that when I scan the plugin phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner takes me out of the camera interface, what I want to do is to stay in it and show me an alert with the scanned code, and to give it ok in the alert to stay in it, to avoid being clicked to enter it.

I'm working with the plugin phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner, in ionic 3

```
public scanQR2() {
this._ButtonText = "Escanear";
this._barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
  if (barcodeData.cancelled) {
    console.log("User cancelled the action!");
    this._ButtonText = "Escanear";
    return false;
  }
  console.log("Scanned successfully!");
  console.log(barcodeData);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

}

I hope that the application when performing a scan stays on the same interface and does not redirect me to another page

Comment: You could call `scanQR2()` in your success callback. So you will start a new scan directly after scanning...

Comment: That way I finish it to be done, thanks friend